# Remove padding from a multidimensional array

Tags: vb.net, matrix, multidimensional-array, encryption, transpose

My assignment is to code a transposition cipher in VB, and I decided that the Route cipher would be the easiest to implement. I have coded the creation of the matrix and the method in which the cipher is created, however, upon extracting the cipher from the array, I received unexpected white space, presumably used to pad the array upon instantiation. Please can you tell me how I can get around this issue thereby preventing white space that wasn't in the original `unciphered` string?

```
Sub Main()
    Console.Write("Please enter the string that you would like to encipher: ")
    Dim Unciphered As String = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Unciphered = {0}", Unciphered)
    Dim Length = Unciphered.Length()
    Dim Rows = Math.Ceiling((Length / 4) * 3)
    Dim Cols = Math.Ceiling(Length / 4)
    Dim Matrix(Rows, Cols) As Char
    Dim Idx As Integer = 0
    For Row = 0 To Rows
        For Column = 0 To Cols
            If (Idx < Unciphered.Length) Then
                Matrix(Row, Column) = Unciphered.Chars(Idx)
                Idx += 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Matrix: ")
    Console.WriteLine()
    For Column = 0 To Cols
        For Row = 0 To Rows
            Console.Write(Matrix(Row, Column))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
    Dim Ciphered As String = ""
    For Column = 0 To Cols
        For Row = 0 To Rows
            Ciphered = String.Concat(Ciphered, Matrix(Row, Column))
        Next
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Ciphered string is: ")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine(Ciphered)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Length = {0}", Ciphered.Length)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide the output u are expecting and the output from this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are fixed length.  If your data doesn't fill the array you either have to keep track of which index(es) constitute the end(s) of the array or ReDim the array to fit the data.

An easier solution is using a dynamic List(Of List(Of Char)).  You access it in a similar way(`Matrix(1)(3)`) but use the Count - 1 as the limits of the loops

Filling the matrix would be something like this:

```
Dim Matrix As New List(Of List(Of Char))
For rows = 0 to Unciphered.Length-1 Step 4
    For cols = 0 to 3
        If (Unciphered.Length - 1) <= (rows + cols) Then
            Matrix(rows).Add(Unciphered(rows + cols))
        Else
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Now the matrix has no padding.